# move files whose creation time or modified time is less than 25 mins to a different folder

Tags: 18.04, bash

I want move a file from dir1 to dir2 , but the catch is it should move if the creation time or modified time is less than 25 mins.

please suggest command for this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `find` command. It allows to find files changed after a specified time. The `-type f` option allows to specify only files, not directories, should be found. The `-mtime` option allows to specify a period. The `-exec` option allows to do something with the found file. See `man find` for how `find` works and find one of many tutorials on line that teach you how to do this.